# C# LinQ Group By Multiple Columns Find Differences in Data

Tags: c#, linq

I've looked through all the posts with Group By, and I think I have somewhat of a handle on it. However, what I'm trying to do is a bit different.

A summary is I have multiple rows of data that are nearly identical except for one or more columns. An example use case would be I have a Kung Fu studio in multiple locations with the same name, and I need to list the same studio name but associate the list of black belts at each studio. Better yet, each address.

Ultimately, my goal is to create a display element that has the studio ID and then a list of Kung Fu instructors. Likewise, the single studio ID with different addresses. I have no control over how the original data was presented, and I need to deal with the rows as I have them available.

I think I have a mechanism for doing just this, but the process is fairly convoluted. I'm wondering if there is an easier mechanism, so I'm hoping for some assistance.

(I know, I probably don't need all the `.ToList()` that I used, but I left them in as this was a work in progress.)

Here is my complete code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConGroupByTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KungFuStudio> studios = KungFuStudio.GetStudios();

            //
            // Get Black Belt per Studio ID
            //
            var uniqueBBSubQuery =
                (
                    (from studio in studios
                     group studio.ID by new { studio.ID, studio.BlackBelt } into std
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = std.Key.ID,
                         BlackBelt = std.Key.BlackBelt,
                         Count = std.Count()
                     }).Where(std => std.Count == 1).ToList()
                ).ToList()
                .GroupBy(gb => new { ID = gb.ID })
                .Select(gb => new { ID = gb.Key.ID, Count = gb.Count() })
                .Where(gb => gb.Count > 1)
                .ToList();

            // I now know which studiio has multiple instructors for each ID
            var uniqueBBQuery = studios
                .Where(std => uniqueBBSubQuery.Any(s => s.ID.Equals(std.ID)))
                .ToList();

            //
            // Get Address per Studio ID
            //
            var byAddressSubQuery =
                (
                        (
                        from studio in studios
                        group studio.ID by new
                        {
                            studio.ID,
                            studio.Address,
                            studio.City,
                            studio.State,
                            studio.Zip
                        } into std
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = std.Key.ID,
                            Address = std.Key.Address,
                            City = std.Key.City,
                            State = std.Key.State,
                            Zip = std.Key.Zip,
                            Count = std.Count()
                        }
                    )
                    .Where(std => std.Count == 1)
                    .ToList()
                )
                .GroupBy(gb => new { ID = gb.ID })
                .Select(gb => new { ID = gb.Key.ID, Count = gb.Count() })
                .Where(gb => gb.Count > 1)
                .ToList();

            // I now know which studios have multiple addresses for the same ID.
            var uniqueStudioAddressQuery = studios
                .Where(std => byAddressSubQuery.Any(s => s.ID.Equals(std.ID)))
                .ToList();

            Debug.WriteLine("Break");
        }
    }

    public class KungFuStudio
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string BlackBelt { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public KungFuStudio() { }

        public static List<KungFuStudio> GetStudios()
        {
            List<KungFuStudio> studios = new List<KungFuStudio>()
            {
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Maim Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sifu Dan", Address="5 Maim ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12345"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Maim Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sijo George",  Address="5 Maim ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12345"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Maim Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sigung Hu Man",  Address="5 Maim ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12345"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Cresent Kick Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sifu John", Address="Cresent Kick ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12346"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Cresent Kick Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sifu Mary.", Address="Cresent Kick ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12346"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Leg Sweep Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sijo Flora", Address="Leg Sweep ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12346"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Leg Sweep Street Studio", BlackBelt="Sijo Flora", Address="Ground Fighting ST", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12347"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Kickboxer Lane Studio", BlackBelt="Sifu Le Ge", Address="Kickboxer LN", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12348"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Plum Flower Fist Studio", BlackBelt="Sigung O. Penn Palm", Address="Plum Flower BLVD", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12349"},
                new KungFuStudio(){ID="Round House Studio", BlackBelt="Sifu Innes Stepp", Address="Round House AVE", City="Kickbutt", State="NY", Zip="12341"}
            };

            return studios;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant and easier way to perform this kind of grouping query? I think I could do it fairly easily in SQL, but I'm not using SQL. The data comes from an Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of instructors for every studio you can just group the data by `ID` and get a list of distinct `BlackBelt` values using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var instructors = studios.GroupBy(s => s.ID, s => s.BlackBelt)
    .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Instructors = g.Distinct().ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

The same can be done for the addresses

```cs
var addresses= studios.GroupBy(s => s.ID, s => s.Address)
    .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Addresses = g.Distinct().ToList() })
    .ToList();
```